# Any tool to measure progressive download of video?

Tags: linux, mozilla, progressive-download

Can you suggest a tool(Linux based) to measure dynamically the amount of data being downloaded or buffered 
by a video(progressive download like Youtube video) that is being played in a browser(Mozilla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifconfig eth0`:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ...
      inet ...
      inet6 ...
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9278084 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4290251 errors:0 dropped:103 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:10351665680 (10.3 GB)  TX bytes:485621573 (485.6 MB)
      Interrupt:45 Base address:0xc000
```

Make sure that the browser is the only thing that's running and the measurement should be pretty accurate.

There are other tools like `lsof(8)` but those don't work well with browsers since the browser doesn't *have* to keep a connection open, so the output will change all the time and you'll lose data when the connection is closed.

Or you can install a local proxy server like `squid` and enable statistics for it.

Comment: I was able to measure it by using a proxy. Thanks for the idea.